# Unknown Verilog error asking for End after else

Tags: verilog

```
module blank(
  input[7:0]r1,
  input[7:0]g1,
  input[7:0]b1,
  input en1,
  output reg[7:0] r2,
  output reg[7:0] g2,
  output reg[7:0] b2,
  output en2
);

always @(*)
begin 
  if ( 48 < r2 < 255  &&  0 < g2 < 223  && 0  < b2 < 196 ) 
     r2 = 255;
     g2 = 255;
     b2 = 255;
  else   
     r2 = 0;
     g2 = 0;
     b2 = 0;
end
endmodule
```

This is used for a threshold, I want it to be able to detect human skin color and turn it to white and others to black.

Comment: What is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at blank.v(21) near text "else";  expecting "end"

Comment: You have `begin`, but you forgot about `end`, but there are also other problems with your code.

Comment: ya there's end and endmodule at the bottom i forget to add it in the code sorry ! but the error is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments from Qui, but there is another issue.  It looks like you are a Python programmer and thought that `48 < r1 < 255` would check if r1 is between 48 and 255.  That doesn't work in Verilog.  Instead it will check whether r1 is > 48 and from that produce a 0 or 1.  It will then check that 0 or 1 against 255 which will always be true.  I've rewritten the equation:

```
always @(*)
begin 
  if ( 48 < r1 && r1 < 255  &&  0 < g1 && g1 < 223  && 0 < b1 && b1 < 196 ) begin
    r2 = 255;
    g2 = 255;
    b2 = 255;
  end else begin   
    r2 = 0;
    g2 = 0;
    b2 = 0;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple problems:

1. Your condition in `if-else` should probably depend on the inputs, not the outputs.
2. Like in C, Java, etc. you need `{}` after `if-else`, that in Verilog you need `begin-end` to be able to perform more than one action.

Your code should look like following:

```
always @(*)
begin 
  if ( 48 < r1 &&  ...  && b1 < 196 ) begin
    r2 = 255;
    g2 = 255;
    b2 = 255;
  end else begin   
    r2 = 0;
    g2 = 0;
    b2 = 0;
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks guy for the help there's still some error but once i added assign en2= en1 the error has been solved :)